# C++ return a string or an int depending on input

Tags: c++

I know a function can only return one type of value, but I'm not sure how else to phrase this.

My function finds a factorial, and I want to print an error message if the input is less than 0.

```
int fact(int a){
    if (a>=0){
        //calculate factorial
        }
        return(product);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Factorials of negative numbers are not defined\n";
        return(0);
    }
}
```

This works, but I only want the error message to be displayed if `a` is less than 0. Right now, my output for negatives is

```
Take the factorial of: -2
Factorials of negative numbers are not defined
0
```

I know it's a minor complaint, but is there any way to get rid of the 0? Returning `NULL` still prints the 0. Removing `return(0)` from the else statement prints 4757824.

Comment: Return -1 and check against the return value before printing it.

Comment: As an aside it's a terrible idea, but you could return either a string or an int using a `std::variant<int, std::string>`.

Comment: @PaulRooney Could you elaborate on why it's a terrible idea? Is it because variant isn't widely supported yet?

Comment: @EmilioGarcia It's not a good idea because it's unnecessary and it burdens the caller with having to figure out what the actual return type is. Then every time you call the `fact` function you'll have to pick apart the return value before you can use the actual answer. And why would `fact` need to return a string anyway? What would that string contain? `fact` should do one thing and do it well: calculate and return the factorial. That is its focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Separation of concerns" your `fact()` method is both calculating the factorial and printing an error. It really shouldn't do both!

Why not have `fact()` return some known but not legal value (say -1) when an error occurs. The calling code can then check whether `fact()` worked or not.

Don't forget you will have another error condition if the input is too big...

Comment: Also might be worthwhile to do the data validation before calling the function.

Comment: @MikelF That is another solution - especially if `fact()` is only called once ;-)

Comment: So instead of checking the value of `a` inside `fact()`, I should check if it's too small/large in `main()`, and then print the error from `main()` as well?

Comment: @EmilioGarcia Checking outside `fact()` (aka in `main()`) is MikelF's solution. My answer says check inside `fact()` but return an error value if the input is out of range. Both work and both are valid. Advantage of my answer is that if you call `fact()` from multiple places you don't have to remember to check before calling it each time.

Comment: Ah so do something like `return(-1)` in `fact()`, but then check that `fact(x)` is positive from inside `main()`?

If I do it this way, wouldn't I still have to check that `fact()` is positive every time I call it? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @EmilioGarcia Yes. You will have to check for an error on each call